# How to put 0 instead of blank in rtf template

Tags: oracle, templates, business-intelligence, bi-publisher, oracle-bi

[see sample report output with blank fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqkuY.png)

I tried this code see image[this is the code I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xWq0.png)
But the 0 was added to the end of each values. See the image below [it's looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw3Zd.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

```
<?xdofx:if your_element!='' then your_element else 0 end if?>

<?xdoxslt:ifelse(your_element!='', your_element, 0)?>
```

Comment: thanks, dio you know how to do it when it's group?

Comment: <?xdofx:if RESULT_VALUE !='' THEN <?if:count(current-group()[VALUE_DATE=$VAL])?><?current-group()[VALUE_DATE=$VAL]/RESULT_VALUE?><?end if?>else 0<?end if?>

Comment: the "else 0" was added to each resut value,
It looks like this>>> 589else0

Comment: I also tried <?xdofx:if RESULT_VALUE =0 THEN 0 else <?if:count(current-group()[VALUE_DATE=$VAL])?><?current-group()[VALUE_DATE=$VAL]/RESULT_VALUE?><?end if?><?end if?>

Comment: But still blank

Comment: I used dynamic column display in rtf template, only those with value will be displayed in the report

Comment: I also tried this one but still not working

Comment: <?xdofx:if current-group()[VALUE_DATE=$VAL]/RESULT_VALUE ='' THEN 0 else <?if:count(current-group()[VALUE_DATE=$VAL])?><?current-group()[VALUE_DATE=$VAL]/RESULT_VALUE?><?end if?><?end if?>

Comment: @Eyei https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPRD/GUID-F2694AE0-F27C-4808-95F6-637F68EC0B8D.htm#BIPRD2518 maybe could help

Comment: @Eyei When you are checking if something is  or isn't there - always check for negation like SOMETHING!=''

Answer (score 0):

To me, the simplest way to do that is to use `NVL` function in query that populates the report, e.g.

```
select nvl(that_value, 0) as value
from ...
```

which means that it'll return value (if it exists) or `0` (if value doesn't exist).

Comment: Ye, but I already added nvl function in the query. Since the template is only displaying dynamic columns if there only values. I don't know how to display 0 in the the template